# Salt: Unpack a tar.gz from a private github repository release

Tags: salt-stack

Using salt, how do you unpack a tar.gz from a private github repository release?

So far I've not found any documentation that addresses this use case.

Specifically, if I understand correctly, passing a token vai a HTTP header - however that could be mistaken.

Comment: What have you tried? Are you facing any issues with your attempt?

Comment: @seshadri_c I've tried the managed file state.  the issue is no where is there the ability to authenticate with the GH token? Or have I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

Since the `git` state allows us authenticate to a Git repository, I can suggest a 2 step process.

1. Clone the repository with [git state](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.git.html)
2. Extract the file with [archive state](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.archive.html)

Example:

```yaml
clone-git-repo:
  git.latest:
    - name: https://mygitrepo.com/user/myrepo.git
    - target: /home/user/myrepo
    - https_user: username
    - https_pass: secret

extract-archive:
  archive.extracted:
    - name: /tmp
    - source: file:///home/user/myrepo/archive.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thanks @seshadri_c, I now realised my question had assumed releases would be implicit in the question.  I've updated the question.  Apologies.